# Máscara condicional para telefone (com 8 ou 9 dígitos) no Ui Mask. Como fazer?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

Estou usando o [`ui.mask`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask) para fazer as máscaras dos inputs. Eu tenho um formulário cujo campo poderá receber tanto um valor de um telefone como de um celular.

Tenho um atualmente um `input` similar a esse:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="cliente.telefone" name="telefone" ui-mask="(99)9?9999-9999" />
```

Com essa definição no `ui-mask` a intenção era que, se a pessoa preenchesse apenas 8 dígitos, a formatação ficaria como `(33)3333-3333`; e, se preenchesse 9, ficaria como `(33)99999-9999`.

Teria como fazer esse tipo de máscara condicional no Ui Mask?

Answer (score 2):

O componente deveria tratar este caso, assim como outros plugins parecidos. Porém, eu criei uma diretiva que resolve teu problema. Segue abaixo:

```
// no Controller

$scope.cliente = { telefone: 0 }
$scope.phoneMask = "(99) 9999-9999";

//HTML

<input type='text' ng-model='cliente.telefone' ui-mask="{{phoneMask}}" mask-change="phoneMask" />

// Diretiva

app.directive('maskChange', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            maskChange: "=",
        },
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {

            var novoTel, flag = false, val;

            elem.off('keyup');
            elem.on('keyup', function(ev) {

                if (/^\d+$/.test(ev.key) || ev.key == 'Backspace' || ev.key == 'Delete') {

                    novoTel = String(ngModel.$viewValue).replace(/[\(\)\_\-/\s]/g, '')

                    if (novoTel.length == 10 && !flag) {
                        flag = true;
                        scope.maskChange = "(99) 9999-9999";
                        scope.$apply();
                    } else if (novoTel.length == 10 && flag) {
                        flag = false;
                        scope.maskChange = "(99) 9?9999-9999";

                        scope.$apply();
                        ngModel.$viewValue += ev.key
                        ngModel.$render();

                    } else if (novoTel.length < 10) {
                        flag = false;
                    }
                }
            })
        }

    };
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar `ui-br-phone-number` da biblioteca [angular-input-masks](https://assisrafael.github.io/angular-input-masks/), por exemplo:

```
<input type="text" ui-br-phone-number  />
```

Answer (score 1):

Como **sugestão alternativa** você pode usar o https://github.com/assisrafael/angular-input-masks, baixe o `angular-input-masks-standalone.min.js` via https://github.com/assisrafael/angular-input-masks/releases e adicione em sua página assim:

```
<script src="angular-input-masks-standalone.min.js"></script>
```

Se usa [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com) para instalar as dependências então instale via linha de comando, assim:

```
npm install --save angular-input-masks
```

Deve adicionar assim:

```
angular.module('demo', ['ui.utils.masks'])
```

E no `input` deve ficar assim:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="cliente.telefone" name="telefone" ui-br-phone-number>
```